# Greek letters doesn't show when use charter package

Tags: fonts, fontspec, greek

I download to my laptop CMU Serif font for greek letters, but when I insert charter package (because i want to write english bold text with it) the regular greek letters doesn't show. This is my code

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\chapter{Chapter 1}
This is a Greek text "Ελλάδα" and this is a {\fontfamily{bch}\bfseries\selectfont bold} text
\end{document}
```

This is my first question. 
The second is does anyone know if there are charter characters for greek letters?

Comment: `charter` probably doesn't have Greek glyphs. If you are using `fontspec`, you should probably load `polyglossia` and set a font for Greek.

Comment: I set fonts for greek in the \setmainfont{CMU Serif}, but for some reason \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} make the problem. If I set \usepackage{fontspec}
 after \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, I have the greek leters, but not the bold style from charter.

Comment: Oh, right! If you use `fontspec` you should not load `fontenc` (except in certain circumstances and when you know what you are doing).

Comment: Do you know how to use fontenc's bold font without insert fonttenc?

Comment: `fontenc` doesn't 'have' bold. A font has it or it doesn't. I'd do a`\newfontfamily\charter{XCharter}` and then, say, `{\charter\bfseries bold}`

Comment: Just by way of explanation: `fontenc` just sets the output font encoding e.g. to `T1` *as opposed to* a unicode encoding. So that's what LaTeX uses and `T1` doesn't support Greek.

Comment: You are loading a whole bunch of competing/conflicting stuff for fonts and font encodings. Get rid of most of it. (e.g. why `\usepackage{lmodern} when `fontspec` uses opentype LM by default anyway?)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

If I insert after `\begin{document}` the magic code

```
\expandafter\show\the\font
```

XeTeX answers by

```
\T1/CMUSerif(0)/m/n/10=select font ecrm1000
```

What does this mean?

- `T1` is the current output encoding
- `CMUSerif(0)` is the current font family
- `ecrm1000` is the name of the corresponding font file

Before this, you also get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/CMUSerif(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 7.
```

which warns you that `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` basically had no effect. Well *it has* some effects: it undoes any setting made by `lmodern` and `charter`.

Note that neither `lmodern` nor `charter` are compatible with (Xe|Lua)LaTeX/`fontspec`. If you want `CMU Serif` as your main font, just declare it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
This is a Greek text ``Ελλάδα''

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want Charter as the main font, you should have a version of it that supports Greek. The XCharter font distributed with TeX Live doesn't.